# Как получить определённую папку из полного пути к файлу

Tags: c#

Как получить мне из этих путей определённые папки: `Shepard`, `Worms`, `Ori and the Blind Forest DE` ???  Все эти пути находятся в `List<string>`

```
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Shepard\setting\modules\Viewer\Path.ini
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Worms\setting\set.bin
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Ori and the Blind Forest DE\settings.bin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
string path = @"C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Shepard\setting\modules\Viewer\Path.ini";
string[] pathTokens = path.Split('\\');
foreach (string token in pathTokens)
{
    Console.WriteLine(token);
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
C:
Users
admin
AppData
Roaming
Shepard
setting
modules
Viewer
Path.ini
```

Comment: А как можно обойти `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\`` и получить первую папку?

Comment: @Zidox вы же умеете работать с массивами? `pathTokens[5]`.